# Remove HTML tags from a String with content

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I have a `string = "195121<span class="up">+432</span>"`. I need regEx to remove tags with its content (result `string = "195121"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below capturing group based regex.

```
string.replaceAll("(?s)<(\\w+)\\b[^<>]*>.*?</\\1>", "");
```

Comment: Thak you! Avinash Raj

Comment: @NodirbekShamsiyev If this solved your problem don't forget to accept by clicking the checkbox to the left.

Answer (score 2):

The main regex works for me are below; It removes all content with a given tag name.

```
"(?is)<your_tag_name[^>]+>.*?<\\/your_tag_name>"
```

I manage it this way. Hope it helps others.

```
var data = "<p>Dhaka is the capital city of Bangladesh " +
    "and many palaces and mosques remain. This is" +
    " fast-growing modern metropolis.</p>\\r\\n<p>&lt;flightnode to=\"CXB\"&gt;&lt;/flightnode&gt;</p>"
```

First replace **&lt;** and **&gt;** to < and >

```
// This replacement not needed if it's already been there
data = data.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">")
```

Then print & check it.

```
println("\n\n $data")

> //output //-> <p>Dhaka is the capital city of Bangladesh and many
> palaces and mosques remain. This is fast-growing modern
> metropolis.</p><p><flightnode to="CXB"></flightnode></p>
```

Set tags **array** you want to **remove** with its **elements**;

```
val tag = arrayOf("flightnode", "hotelnode ", "packagenode")
```

Then loop throught your string

```
for (value in tag) {
    val patternString = "(?is)<$value[^>]+>.*?<\\/$value>"
    val pattern = compile(patternString)
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(data)
    println("\n\n" + matcher.find())
    data = matcher.replaceAll("")
}
```

Print to check it.

```
println("\n\n" + data)

> // output // -> <p>Dhaka is the capital city of Bangladesh and many
> palaces and mosques remain. This is fast-growing modern
> metropolis.</p>\r\n<p></p>
```

Thanks my ex-colleague [@masud-bappy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8024603/masud-bappy) for creating regex.